# Counting on minesweeper

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, algorithms

Given a minesweeper configuration. How many way are there to fill it to make the configuration correct.

Is there any better solution than brute-force method ?

Example: 
Given configuration:
`1_11_2__b` (b = bomb, _ = blank)

one way to fill it is:
`1b11b2b2b`

Comment: What's a minesweeper configuration?

Comment: Do you mean the Windows game Minesweeper? Also, you'll have to be clearer about what "filling it with number 0,1, or 2" means.

Comment: Can you precise your question? What is a "configuration". A set of mines, or a set of visible squares, or a size of borad?

Comment: Please wait a second, I'll edit my question

Comment: Bilou06: all of them, A set of visible mines and a set of visible squares and size of board. Sorry for my english.

Comment: In this case, you can deduce that any $2$ will have a bomb on either side, and that any $1$ on the edge will have a bomb next to it.  In this case, the only free choice is the last blank, so it's clear that there are $2$ ways to fill the configuration.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Standard 2D minesweeper has been shown to be [NP complete](http://web.mat.bham.ac.uk/R.W.Kaye/minesw/ordmsw.htm)-that finding if there is a way to solve a given partially filled in board is hard.  I would guess that 1D is not, there isn't enough room to make the required structures.  In any case, you probably want one pass that fills in all the squares that have to be one kind or the other-for example your first blank.  That would solve all the squares except the last, which can be b or 2.  Then start a backtracking algorithm-try one and see if it works, then the other.  You may well have to split into subcases.  Dynamic programming makes structuring this easier.